# apex class error when using Id based on selected value on vf

Tags: apex, visualforce

can help me this error?

This error occur at

LIST empMember = [SELECT Id, Name, Full_Name__r.Name FROM HREMPINFO__c WHERE Id IN 
                                    (SELECT Employee_No__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod)
                                    ORDER BY Name];

error message : Didn't understand relationship 'Period__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

my controller :

```
public with sharing class PreProcessController {

public SelectOption[] selectedEmployee { get; set; }
public SelectOption[] allContacts { get; set; }
public String selectedPeriod { get; set; }
Public String ProcessAll {get; set;}
Public Integer Count=0;
public String message { get; set; }
public String picklistVal;

public List<selectOption> getPeriod() {        
    List<selectOption> listPeriod = new List<selectOption>(); 
    listPeriod.add(new selectOption('', '- None -')); 
    for (PYSETPAYPERIOD__c perCode : [SELECT Id, Name, Process_Flag__c FROM PYSETPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Process_Flag__c < 4 OR Process_Flag__c = NULL ORDER BY Name]) {         
        listPeriod.add(new selectOption(perCode.id, perCode.Name));       
    } 
    return listPeriod;
}
public PreProcessController() {}
public LIST<SelectOption> GetAllEmployee() {
    LIST<HREMPINFO__c> empMember = [SELECT Id, Name, Full_Name__r.Name FROM HREMPINFO__c WHERE Id IN 
                                    (SELECT Employee_No__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod)
                                    ORDER BY Name];

    LIST<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c> empAssignment = [SELECT Position_Name__c, Position_Name__r.Name, Employee_No__c  FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c];

    LIST<SelectOption> empList = new LIST<SelectOption>();

    for(HREMPINFO__c eM : empMember){
        for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c eA : empAssignment){
            if(eA.Employee_No__c == eM.Id){
                picklistVal = eM.Full_Name__r.Name + ' - ' + eM.Name + ' - ' +eA.Position_Name__r.Name;
                empList.add(new SelectOption(eM.Id, picklistVal));}
            }
        }
        return empList;
    }

public PageReference save() {
    message = 'Work'+Count;
    Boolean first = true;
    for ( SelectOption so : selectedContacts ) {
        if (!first) {
            message += ', ';
        }
        message += so.getLabel() + ' (' + so.getValue() + ')';
        first = false;
    }

    return null; }      
}
```

my vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="PreProcessController">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Payroll Name" for="listPeriod"/>
                <apex:selectList id="listPeriod" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPeriod}" style="width:150px">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Period}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="listEmployee"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll" value="{!ProcessAll}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="listEmployee" />
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee">
            <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}"
                                   rightLabel="Selected Employee"
                                   rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}"
                                   size="14"
                                   width="475px"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:outputText >{!message}</apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Does `Period__c` look up to itself? It seems like the simplest field path would be `Period__c` in place of `Period__r.Period__r.Id`.

Comment: nope, it was lookup field from object a, then lookup again from object b, so it was 2 level lookup @AdrianLarson

Comment: As the error message says, if you are not sure about the correct API name, better to have a look at the WSDL first.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like security issue. Make sure your current account has field access to period__c field and related object

Comment: hmm oke then, thanks for answer sir, u already comment at all my question, very very appreciate that sir! :) i will find it myself then hehe @LanceShi

Comment: While Visualforce automatically handles object and field level CRUD permissions automatically, Apex does not. See e.g. [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS). So not a security issue (and the error message in the question is pretty clear).

Comment: @KeithC hmm, LanceShi already know my problem, cause i already post about my problem in many context, and he know what i'm doing and what is my problem, but i find the answer now, my button cant operation because of my reRender,  now i need to know how to isolate the reRender and action. any idea? i post it in another question. 
Thanks!